# Power BI - How to drop data before uploading the report to the Reporting Server

Tags: database, powerbi, reloaddata

`Is there any way to drop data and publish the report to the reporting server? On the reporting server we want to have scheduled refresh for the data.`

Right now, the scenario is like we are picking data from a SQL server and our PBIX file becomes around 600MB. We are timing out while uploading the PBIX file to the reporting server. `So we are looking for dropping the data from the report before uploading it to the reporting server.`

Comment: Are you using Power BI Premium or Premium Per User by chance?  If so, you can use parameters with M and deployment pipelines to filter the data locally and restore once published

Comment: We are using Power BI desktop version for development and we push the report to on-premises reporting server. We are not using Power BI service (cloud) -@Daryl Wenman-Bateson

Comment: convert pbix to pbit and deploy. then refresh.